# Entering a char in an integer user input doesn't return an error, instead converts it into an integer?

Tags: c

I wrote a program to return the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence, n being user inputted. The program works fine, but I entered a letter instead of an integer to see what would happen, expecting a crash or an error message, but instead it converted the letter a into the number 6422368 (it converted all letters I tried to this same number). Could someone please explain why this happened?

```
/* Fibonacci sequence that returns the nth term */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int previous = 0; // previous term in sequence
    int current = 1; // current term in sequence
    int next; // next term in sequence
    int n; // user input
    int result; // nth term

    printf("Please enter the number of the term in the fibonacci sequence you want to find\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 1) 
    { 
        result = 0;
        printf("Term %d in the fibonacci sequence is: %d", n, result);
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) // calculates nth term
        {
            next = current + previous;
            previous = current;
            current = next;
            if (i == n - 2) 
            {
                result = current;
                printf("Term %d in the fibonacci sequence is: %d", n, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qNsx.png)

Comment: Did you check the return value of `scanf`? What you have is not the converted number, it's *undefined behavior* because `n` ends up being used without being initialized

Comment: `%d` stops when it gets to a non-decimal character.

Comment: Ok I initialized n to 0, and entering a returned nothing, which makes more sense to me. Thanks UnholySheep

Comment: If you want to check user's input, you have to catch it as a string (`scanf("%s", &str)`), check if it's a number and then, convert it to `int`

Comment: Include the output in your question as text, formatted as code. A link to an image of the output is much less useful.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()`.  Initialized `n` to 0 is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter a non-decimal character by using `%d`, `scanf()` return 0 (error) and don't set `n`. When you print it, it's a non-initialized variable, then it prints random value.

If you want to counter the problem, you can get the user's input as `string`, check if it's a correct number, and then convert it to `int`:

```
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int previous = 0; // previous term in sequence
    int current = 1; // current term in sequence
    int next; // next term in sequence
    int n; // to catch str conversion
    int i = -1; // for incrementation
    char str[10]; // user input
    int result; // nth term

    printf("Please enter the number of the term in the fibonacci sequence you want to find\n");
    scanf("%s", &str); // Catch input as string
    while (str[++i])
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) // Check if each characters is a digit
            return -1;
    n = atoi(str); // Convert string to int

    // Rest of the function
```

Comment: Detail: "enter a non-decimal character by using `%d, scanf()` return 0" except for  `'-'`. `'+'`, tab, space, ...  `char str[10];` is insufficient space for text meant as large values of `int`.  The basic idea is good, yet does not do the job.